# Is there a way to set the width of a column in XWPFTableCell(POI)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

The full path of the class is org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell.

The API goes here: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot set the width of column in XWPFTableCell.
But you can always use `HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(int column)` after finished entering data in sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it; to find this I had to study its internal XML schema.

This is a major and very tricky element; I spent several days solving this problem and finally I had managed to solve it using this method of setting the widths of a table cell:

```
private static void setTableColumnWidths(XWPFTable table) {
    table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2000));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3200));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1000));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1000));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1105));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1105));

}
```